# R apply script output in different formats for similar inputs

Tags: r, data-structures, output, apply

I'm using a double apply function to get a list of p-values for cor.test between any two columns of two  tables.

```
hel_plist<-apply(bc, 2, function(x) { apply(otud, 2, function(y) { if (cor.test(x,y,method="spearman", exact=FALSE)$p.value<0.05){cor.test(x,y,method="spearman", exact=FALSE)$p.value}}) })
```

The otud data.frame is 90X11 (90rows,11 colums or  to say dim(otud) 90 11) and will be used with different data.frames.
bc and hel - are both 90X2 data.frame-s - so for both I get 2*11=22 p-values out of functions

```
bc_plist<-apply(bc, 2, function(x) { apply(otud, 2, function(y) { if (cor.test(x,y,method="spearman", exact=FALSE)$p.value<0.05){cor.test(x,y,method="spearman", exact=FALSE)$p.value}}) })
hel_plist<-apply(hel, 2, function(x) { apply(otud, 2, function(y) { if (cor.test(x,y,method="spearman", exact=FALSE)$p.value<0.05){cor.test(x,y,method="spearman", exact=FALSE)$p.value}}) })
```

For bc I will have an output with dim=NULL a list of elements of otunames$bcnames$ p-value (a format that I have always got from these scripts and are happy with)
But for hel I will get and output of dim(hel) 11 2 - an 11X2 table with p-values written inside.

Shortened examples of output.

hel_plist

```
+--------+--------------+--------------+
|        | axis1        | axis2        |
+--------+--------------+--------------+
| Otu037 | 1.126362e-18 | 0.01158251   |
| Otu005 | 3.017458e-2  | NULL         |
| Otu068 | 0.00476002   | NULL         |
| Otu070 | 1.27646e-15  | 5.252419e-07 |
+--------+--------------+--------------+
```

bc_plist

```
$axis1
$axis1$Otu037
[1] 1.247717e-06

$axis1$Otu005
[1] 1.990313e-05

$axis1$Otu068
[1] 5.664597e-07
```

Why is it like that when the input formats are all the same? (Shortened examples)

bc

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+
| group | axis1     | axis2     |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
| 1B041 | 0.125219  | 0.246319  |
| 1B060 | -0.022412 | -0.030227 |
| 1B197 | -0.088005 | -0.305351 |
| 1B222 | -0.119624 | -0.144123 |
| 1B227 | -0.148946 | -0.061741 |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
```

hel

```
+-------+---------------+---------------+
| group | axis1         | axis2         |
+-------+---------------+---------------+
| 1B041 | -0.0667782322 | -0.1660606406 |
| 1B060 | 0.0214470932  | -0.0611351008 |
| 1B197 | 0.1761876858  | 0.0927570627  |
| 1B222 | 0.0681058251  | 0.0549292399  |
| 1B227 | 0.0516864361  | 0.0774155225  |
| 1B235 | 0.1205676221  | 0.0181712761  |
+-------+---------------+---------------+
```

How could I force my scripts to always produce "flat" outputs as in the case of bc

Answer (score 0):

OK different output-s are caused because of the NULL results from conditional  function in bc_plist case. If I'd to modify code to replace possible NULL-s with NA-s I'd get 2d tables in any case.
So to keep things constant :

```
bc_nmds_plist<-apply(bc_nmds, 2, function(x) { apply(stoma_otud, 2, function(y) { if (cor.test(x,y,method="spearman", exact=FALSE)$p.value<0.05){cor.test(x,y,method="spearman", exact=FALSE)$p.value}else NA}) })
```

And I get a 2d tabel out for bc_nmds_plist too. 
So I guess this thing can be called solved - as I now have a piece of code that produces predictable output on any correct input.
If anyone has any idea how to force the output to conform to previos bc_plist format instead I would still be interested as I do actually prefer that form:

```
$axis1
$axis1$Otu037
[1] 1.247717e-06

$axis1$Otu005
[1] 1.990313e-05

$axis1$Otu068
[1] 5.664597e-07
```